# When creating a Java class in IntelliJ: is there a wizard/menu to select the package and class to extend from?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

One of the features I like of Eclipse is that when creating Java classes, a wizard is available to specify different properties for the class. Like its package, class to extend from...etc (see below in the screen cap).

[image: Eclipse new Java class menu]

Does IntelliJ provide something similar? I created a class but the process wasn't smooth. I had to...mark /java directory as Source Root...create new package...create a new class...and now, I want to extend from a different class other than Object... I would like to avoid doing this step by step, if possible.

I am using IntelliJ Community Edition, version 15.

Comment: the package-step is actually way simpler in IntelliJ than in eclipse.  Instead of adding the package-name in a separate field, you just type the fully-qualified name (`package1.package2.classname`) and the packages are automatically generated.

Comment: Thanks Paul, good tip. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such wizard. Marking the directory as a source root is a one-time action, and is normally taken care of when you create the project. To specify the package, you can enter the package and class name directly in the "New Java class" dialog. If you want to extend a different class, the code completion will help you enter the "extends" or "implements" keyword and specify the base class name.

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer and suggestions @yole. I can say now that the process is more comfortable than what it seemed at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make package at the same time as you create java class.
When you do `right click -> new -> java class` : at the place of the name you can mark

`my.new.package.ClassName` and IntelliJ will create the package : `my.new.package` for you.

For more explication you can visit [this page.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#get-started)

Answer (score 0):

In IJ you don't need to write all of this stuff manually. Just right click on the method an choose `Go to Test` or press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-T</kbd>. This functionality is described on the help page [IntelliJ IDEA 15.0 Help /Creating Tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-tests.html).

> In the Create Test dialog:
>
> - Select the testing library to be used.
> - If the selected library is missing in your module, click the Fix button. As a result, the corresponding library will be automatically added to the module libraries.
> - Define the name and location of the test class to be generated.
>         In the Class name field, specify the name of the stub test class to be generated.
> - In the Superclass field, IntelliJ IDEA suggests the appropriate super class for JUnit3. For JUnit 4 and TestNG, this field is blank.
> - In the Destination package field, define where the generated test class should be placed.
> - Specify whether you want the `setUp()/tearDown()` methods (for JUnit), or the `@Before/@After` annotations to be generated.
>     In the table that shows the list of all the methods of the source class, select the ones you want to generate test methods for.
> - Click OK.

[image: createTest2.png]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers if you hit Alt-Enter on any interface or abstract class name one of the intention options will be to create an implementation.